# understanding a database trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, database-cursor

I am new to triggers and cursors and would like to understand what a particular trigger is doing. Here is the Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_XOnUpdate]
ON TableX
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @XID INT, @XKey NVARCHAR(33)

    DECLARE updated_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT  XID, XKey 
        FROM    INSERTED 
        WHERE   XStatus 
        IN      ('AA', 'BB', 'CC')
    OPEN updated_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM updated_cursor INTO @XID, @XKey
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE usp_UpdateXData @XID, @XKey

        FETCH NEXT FROM updated_cursor INTO @XID, @XKey
    END

    CLOSE updated_cursor
    DEALLOCATE updated_cursor
END
```

Comment: What line don't you understand?

Comment: @TabAlleman I understand that the cursor is enumerating through the data returned by the select, where status IN ('AA', 'BB', 'CC'). I am not understanding the Fetch Next From Part... Is it saying that execute the stored procedure for the IDs and Keys which have status IN ('AA', 'BB', 'CC')?

Comment: FETCH NEXT is a cursor operation.   Google "SQL Cursor Example" for a full explanation.

Comment: Ideally you would get rid of this cursor entirely and create a set based operation instead of calling a stored procedure for each row updated.

Answer (score 3):

**Understanding the Basic of Triggers**
A trigger is an operation that is executed when some kind of event occurs to the database. It can be a data or object change.  Listed below are the different types of tiggers:

**Types of Triggers**

- DML(data manipulation language) triggers (SQL Server 2000- 80.0)
- DDL(data definition language) triggers (SQL Server 2005- 90.0)
- SQLCLR triggers (SQL Server 2005- 90.0)

**Rules of Triggers**

- cannot create or modify Database objects using triggers
- cannot perform any administrative tasks
- cannot pass any kind of parameters
- cannot directly call triggers

**Advantage of Triggers**
Triggers are useful for auditing data changes or auditing database as well as managing business rules.  Below are some examples:

- Triggers can be used to enforce referential integrity (For example you may not be able to apply foreign keys)
- Can access both new values and old values in the database when going to do any insert, update or delete

Drill down further about triggers...
[Understanding the Basic of Triggers](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2009/understanding-the-basic-of-triggers/)
[Understanding SQL Server inserted and deleted tables for DML triggers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/)